# How to ask to the service worker to ignore requests matching a specific URL pattern in Polymer?

Tags: authentication, polymer, firebase-authentication, service-worker

My application is built on [Polymer v2](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/feature-overview) and uses the [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) service for authentication. Actually, I use the [login-fire](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/convoo/login-fire) element. For a better experience on mobile devices, I choose to sign-in with redirect.

In the *"network"* tab of the DevTool (in Chrome) I see that a request containing the `/__/auth/handler?` pattern is sent for requesting Google authentication (for example, if the provider used is Google).

With the service workers enabled, this request is caught and the response is the login page of my application. No login attempted, the response comes from the service worker and I get a `Network Error` from Firebase API because of a timeout.

When I deploy the app without service workers the authentication process is working and I can reach the app.

I tried many ways to config the service workers to ignore all requests to a URL with the `/auth/` pattern but I failed.

See the last version of my config file bellow.

**sw-precache-config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  globPatterns: ['**\/*.{html,js,css,ico}'],
  staticFileGlobs: [
    'bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js',
    'images/*',
    'manifest.json',
  ],
  clientsClaim: true,
  skipWaiting: true,
  navigateFallback: 'index.html',
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: /\/auth\//,
      handler: 'networkOnly',
    },
    {
      urlPattern: /\/bower_components\/webcomponentsjs\/.*.js/,
      handler: 'fastest',
      options: {
        cache: {
          name: 'webcomponentsjs-polyfills-cache',
        },
      },
    },
    {
      urlPattern: /\/images\//,
      handler: 'cacheFirst',
      options: {
        cacheableResponse: {
          statuses: [0, 200],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

**Do you have a better solution? Do you notice what I missed?**

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this to your sw-precache-config.js file

```
  navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^(?!\/auth\/)/],
```

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution this morning actually.

Answer (score 1):

You should only whitelist the paths of your application. This should be known to you.

So everything you do not whitelist, will **not** be served from the serviceworker.

```
navigateFallbackWhitelist: [/^\/news\//,/^\/msg\//, /^\/settings\//],
```

With this example, only `news/*`, `msg/*`,`settings/*` will be delivered.

`/auth/*`,`/api/*`,... will not be caught.